# When can an adverb modify a participial adjective?

Tags: adverbs, syntactic-analysis, parts-of-speech, participles, deverbal-adjectives

Why can you say:

1. the hurriedly passed bill
2. the warmly clothed child

but not:

3. the *here proposed bill
4. the *yesterday scolded child

To me they don't even sound informally understandable, they just sound like nonsense.

Semantically, they are fine.  And the grammar matches cases 1 and 2.

So what makes them so wrong?

Comment: But you _can_ say: "the bill proposed here" and "the child scolded yesterday"

Comment: You think that's bad, try throwing *exactly* or *additionally* or *namely* or *moreover* or *even* or *very* or *quite* or *later* or *enough* or *then* or  *westward* or *everywhere* or *afar* or *near* or *meanwhile* or *sometimes* or *besides* or *behind* or *without* or *outside* or *enough* or *however* at your various participles to see which stick and which fall flat or fail flatly if you prefer. :)  Once you get done with trying it on past participles various and sundry, rewind and try it all again with present participles this time around.

Comment: It's always seemed to me that "here", "there", "yesterday" and "today" are adverbs in name only.  They call them that because then they can "explain" certain ways they are used, when otherwise they'd have to invent new "rules".

Comment: Note that you can say _the child warmly clothed_ but not *_the child yesterday scolded_. The phrase itself is wrong and therefore doesn't permute.

Comment: @tchrist: Do any of them work differently with past participles than with present participles? Of course for the same verb it won't work the same, since the past participle uses the noun as its object while the present uses it as its subject.  "Additionally" for example is hard to use with an intransitive verb in the first place, regardless of whether it's a participle, so I think that's a different issue. If you're suggesting that adverbs can be usefully subclassified into major groups, that's very interesting! If you're suggesting acceptability is totally random, that would be disappointing!

Comment: @HotLicks: Interesting, this category surely includes "Tuesday" and many others. It would be interesting if these turn out to have the same restrictions as adverb phrases.

Comment: ***"In the here-proposed Bill,*** *in the event of a criminal offence being committed by any one of’ the high legal functionaries in question, for the future prevention of such offence punishment is appointed to be inflicted on him. "* From "The Works of Jeremy Bentham" Part 3 By Jeremy Bentham (1843) ++ The point is that these constructions are correct but uncommon.

Comment: @Greybeard: In fact I am asking the question because I see phrases like this all the time, produced by non-native speakers. While I agree that your example sounds ok, I would also describe it as stilted speech, and I hope even Jeremy Bentham would never have talked like that in ordinary conversation. This is still a usage error in ordinary speech and writing -- for example, learners of English should learn to say it differently if they want to be understood.  When you say "these constructions are correct but uncommon", what class of constructions are you talking about?

Comment: @JohnLawler *"Note that you can ... not say *the child yesterday scolded."* I think that is rather prescriptive - but I don't think it wrong. The phrasing is somewhat archaic - but *"The child who was yesterday scolded..." sounds fine.

Comment: @Matt. "Here presented" is certainly valid and most certainly formal. When I said *"these constructions are correct but uncommon"* I am referring to those with unusual syntax that are often copied from an earlier style. These convey far more than the sum of their parts to those native speakers who understand the culture behind them.

Comment: @Greybeard: Ah, "those with unusual syntax" -- here we arrive at exactly the issue. I think "yesterday scolded" is far more unusual than "warmly clothed", and yet the syntax appears to be the same. Either there is some syntactic difference, or it is not the syntax which is unusual. Either way, I would be curious to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Matt Leaving aside the example with “here”, which I don’t see as contentious: we have *the yesterday scolded child* ++ After reading your comment to Hot Licks *“this category surely includes "Tuesday" and many others”* I agree, but a hyphen is required

Thus, **yesterday** is not an adjective or an adverb – it is a **noun** along the lines of the hyphenated adjectives **“moth-eaten”; water-logged” “dog-eared”; “the August-born child…”; “The 2002-made car…”**

As you see it should be “the yesterday-scolded child”.

Comment: @Greybeard: I have trouble seeing "yesterday" as a noun there.  In the other word orders, where an adverbial phrase would be permissible, it is parallel to "in January", not to "January".

Comment: @Greybeard: I still see the "here" example as exceedingly stuffy, and in casual conversation I still regard it as simply a mistake. But I have to agree that seeing things as just right or wrong in an absolute sense is too naive.  I should probably rephrase my question in some way to acknowledge that, but the question still stands. We can also create examples where "yesterday" sounds ok, as in the saying "The yesterday scolded child is today well hushed and mild."

Comment: @ Matt - * I still see the "here" example as exceedingly stuffy* I don't think that matters as far as its being correct is concerned. ***Yesterday - Noun***: Examples used in OED: ++ 1965   J. Lennon & P. McCartney Yesterday in Beatles Lyrics (1998) 92   Suddenly, I'm not half the man I used to be, There's a shadow hanging over me, Oh yesterday came suddenly. - Subject of a sentence ++ 2014   Daily Tel. 5 Sept. (Sport section) 9/1   [He]..is in hospital in Tenerife after being stabbed in the leg in the early hours of yesterday.. - subject of a preposition.

Comment: @ Matt - ***Yesterday - Noun***: Examples used in OED: ++ 1990   Computer Lang. Oct. 29/2 (advt.)    You're trying to write tomorrow's programs with yesterday's tools. - noun in the genitive. ++ a1616   W. Shakespeare Macbeth (1623) v. v. 21   And all our yesterdayes, have lighted Fooles The way to dusty death. - noun in plural ++ 2013   D. J. Flynn War on Football viii. 137   That world exists..as a quaint memory of a yesterday that appears surreal to today. - with indefinite article.

Comment: @Greybeard: Of course yesterday _can_ be a noun. The question is whether it is a noun in the given construction.

Comment: @Matt I answered that above:*Thus, yesterday is not an adjective or an adverb – it is a noun along the lines of the hyphenated adjectives “moth-eaten”; water-logged” “dog-eared”; “the August-born child…”; “The 2002-made car…” As you see it should be “the yesterday-scolded child”*

Comment: @Greybeard: I like your sense of humor. Repeating the examples you already gave where a noun is doing the modifying do not demonstrate that "yesterday" is being used as a noun any more than repeating the examples I already gave where an adverb is doing the modifying would demonstrate that "yesterday" is being used as an adverb. That is why I took the path of comparing with "January" vs. "in January", to try to find a way to directly compare these two alternatives (noun vs. adverb), to see which interpretation fits the original construction better. (This conversation is going a bit meta...)